# Consumir un Web Service de Afip desde .net

Tags: xml, .net, webservice

estoy trabado y no puedo conectarme a un web service que ofrece AFIP (Argentina) 
La verdad es que nunca he trabajado con web services, y para colmo la "ayuda" que ofrecen desde el sitio es pésima.

Esta es la pagina donde esta el funcionamiento general
http://www.afip.gob.ar/ws/documentacion/default.asp --> Resumiendo, se conecta a un ws (WSAA) para conseguir un token y luego con ese token se conecta a los demas ws

Este es la url donde se conecta para conseguir el token de autenticacion
https://wsaahomo.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms

Este es la url donde se conecta al Web Service que quiero utilizar (Comunicaciones Ventanilla Electrónica).
https://infraestructura.afip.gob.ar/ve-ws/services/veconsumer?wsdl

Luego, hay un código de ejemplo para conectarse al WSAA y se baja desde 
http://www.afip.gob.ar/ws/WSAA/ejemplos/dev-wsaa-cliente-dotnet-vb.zip

Mi problema es que no puedo conectarme al web service. Si voy al Visual Studio  y agrego esa dirección como referencia de servicio, me aparecen las funciones que ofrece.

Mi primer pregunta (y suposición, corrijan si estoy equivocado), cuando agrego la referencia al ws, y aparecen las funciones que ofrecen, simplemente tengo que llamar a esas funciones y pasarle los parametros que pide, el visual studio transforma en xml para lograr la comunicacion?
Si esto es asi, como hago para ver el xml que estoy enviando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente: Visual Studio crea un wrapper con funciones a partir de los métodos del web service. Al llamar a las funciones se crea el XML necesario para enviarlo.

Existen varias formas de ver el XML, una de ellas es utilizar [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) y ver el contenido de las solicitudes y las respuestas

Answer (score 4):

Comparto con vos que el manual de la AFIP es pésimo. Lo pude hacer funcionar con el WS de constancia de inscripción. Así es como lo hice yo, al tener casi nada de experiencia en el área no se si será la mejor forma de aplicarlo, pero funciona.

Primero realicé un proyecto con .net core 2.2 y le agregué otro proyecto de Biblioteca de Clases (.NET Framework)

En ese proyecto agregué una referencia de servicio y apunté a `https://wsaahomo.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms?wsdl` Luego clic en finalizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado realicé un método (en el proyecto .net core) para obtener la fecha según AFIP

```
public static DateTime GetNetworkTime()
        {
            const string ntpServer = "time.afip.gov.ar";
            var ntpData = new byte[48];
            ntpData[0] = 0x1B; //LeapIndicator = 0 (no warning), VersionNum = 3 (IPv4 only), Mode = 3 (Client Mode)

            var addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServer).AddressList;
            var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(addresses[0], 123);
            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            socket.Send(ntpData);
            socket.Receive(ntpData);
            socket.Close();

            ulong intPart = (ulong)ntpData[40] << 24 | (ulong)ntpData[41] << 16 | (ulong)ntpData[42] << 8 | (ulong)ntpData[43];
            ulong fractPart = (ulong)ntpData[44] << 24 | (ulong)ntpData[45] << 16 | (ulong)ntpData[46] << 8 | (ulong)ntpData[47];

            var milliseconds = (intPart * 1000) + ((fractPart * 1000) / 0x100000000L);
            var networkDateTime = (new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)).AddMilliseconds((long)milliseconds);

            return networkDateTime;
        }
```

Y por último el método para obtener el CMS para mandar al LoginCMS de AFIP y que me de el token y el sign

```
private string Ticket()
        {
            var fechaAfip = GetNetworkTime();
            var generateTimeAfip = fechaAfip.AddMinutes(-2); //resto algunos minutos para que no me error en el pedido de acuerdo a instrucciones del manual
            var fechaPedido = DateTimeOffset.Parse(generateTimeAfip.AddHours(-3).ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz");

            var expirationTimeAfip = fechaAfip.AddMinutes(+2); //lo mismo que en el generateTimeAfip 
            var fechaExpira = DateTimeOffset.Parse(expirationTimeAfip.AddHours(-3).ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz");

            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

            var archivo = //ubicación de tu archivo .pfx

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(archivo, "tupass", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var encodingUTF = Encoding.UTF8;

            xml.LoadXml("<loginTicketRequest><header><uniqueId></uniqueId><generationTime></generationTime><expirationTime></expirationTime></header><service></service></loginTicketRequest>");

            var unique = xml.SelectSingleNode("//uniqueId");
            var generateTime = xml.SelectSingleNode("//generationTime");
            var expirationTime = xml.SelectSingleNode("//expirationTime");
            var service = xml.SelectSingleNode("//service");

            unique.InnerText = "1";
            generateTime.InnerText = fechaPedido;
            expirationTime.InnerText = fechaExpira;
            service.InnerText = "ws_sr_constancia_inscripcion";
            var outXml = xml.InnerXml;

            byte[] msgBytes = encodingUTF.GetBytes(outXml);

            ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(msgBytes);
            SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo);
            CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, certificate);
            cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
            signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);

            byte[] cmsCodificado = signedCms.Encode();

            var codBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(cmsCodificado);

            return codBase64;
        }
```

Para generar el certificado `.pfx` seguí los pasos que estan en el manual `http://www.afip.gob.ar/ws/WSASS/WSASS_manual.pdf` apartado 5.1

Para finalmente obtener el token y el sign lo realicé de la siguiente manera:

```
string ticket = Ticket();
            LoginAfip.LoginCMSClient loginCMS = new LoginAfip.LoginCMSClient();
            var login = await loginCMS.loginCmsAsync(ticket);

            var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(login.loginCmsReturn);
            var token = xdoc.Descendants().First(node => node.Name == "token").Value;
            var sign = xdoc.Descendants().First(node => node.Name == "sign").Value;
            var expTime = xdoc.Descendants().First(node => node.Name == "expirationTime").Value;
```

Como el token es válido para las próximas 12 horas, deberías tener una manera de almacenarlo y reutilizarlo.

Así es como lo pude hacer funcionar ayer mismo. Lo probé en modo producción y me funciono de maravillas.

Espero se entienda la solución. Estoy abierto a opiniones para mejorar la implementación.

Saludos.

Comment: Me sirvio tu respuesta. Gracias! Ahora bien una vez almacenado el token hay que compararlo con la fecha/hora actual mas 12 horas? O bien `var expirationTimeAfip = fechaAfip.AddMinutes(+2);` deberia ser `var expirationTimeAfip = fechaAfip.AddHours(12)`

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido. Me explico mejor. El response al pedido del token viene con la fecha de expiración. El que mencionas de agregar dos minutos es al generar el XML para realizar la petición. Si no le agregas esos "minutitos" al request, AFIP te rechaza el pedido porque esa fecha ya pasó. Cuando recibes el response, fijate en esta línea ```var expTime = xdoc.Descendants().First(node => node.Name == "expirationTime").Value;``` donde ahí se lee la fecha de expiración que es la que tenes que almacenar. Saludos.

Comment: el archivo .pfx que se obtiene en wsass solosirve para homologacion? como seria en produccion

Comment: @Caruso Hola como estas?. Primero deberías generar el CSR. Link del manual de AFIP para realizarlo: [link](https://www.afip.gob.ar/ws/WSAA/WSAA.ObtenerCertificado.pdf). Una vez que tengas el CSR, lo tenes que subir a AFIP. Ingresando con clave fiscal > Administración de Certificados Digitales. Si ya habías subido antes alguno, deberías poder verlos. Caso contrario haces clic "Agregar alias". Completas el campo de "Nombre" y luego das clic en examinar para seleccionar el archivo que creaste antes. Si todo sale bien, podrás bajar el certificar crt que luego lo deberías exportar a pfx

Comment: @Caruso y respondiendo a tu consulta. Si, tenes un certificado para producción y otro para homologación. Tene en cuenta que un certificado en producción es válido por dos años (creo). Para que anotes la fecha de vencimiento y lo renueves en su momento. En ese caso cuando veas el alias le das en "Ver", luego ahí le das en "Agregar certificado". Seleccionas el mismo que habías creado antes y te renueva por dos años mas.