# ¿Como hacer una Web References a AFIP.WSAA?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tengo un proyecto de asp.net c# en el cual hago la referencia al web service de la afip y todo joya, pero, en un nuevo proyecto de asp.net core c#, no logro que haga la referencia correctamente. si necesitan algun codigo para ejemplificar lo agrego, pero creo que no hay nada relevante. pongo donde estoy teniendo problema.

el servicio al que hago referencia es el siguiente: 
https://wsaahomo.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms?wsdl

`AFIP.WSAA.LoginCMSService servicio = new AFIP.WSAA.LoginCMSService();`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando intento hacer esto, en asp.net core, no encuentro LoginCMSService.

aca esta la referancia que hago en asp.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca esta la referencia, que hice en asp.net core, que segun entiendo se hace conectando un servico, esto es lo que estoy haciendo mal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando intento hacer la referencia al servicio me da dos opciones, OpenAPI y gRPC. probe las 2 y no logro acceder a esa referencia.

Comment: Esas clases de donde salen??? digo la clase AFIP.WSAA.. salen de la pagina de la afip?

Comment: es el nombre que le pongo yo a la referencia, ahí lo detalle en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

En `asp.net core` las cosas cambiaron para referencia a servicio algo ams antiguos como es el caso de este que aun sigue usando `wsdl`

[Use the WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)

deberias ver en `Connected Services`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la opcion para servicio de `WCF`, sino esta verifica con la opcion `Find more services...`

Quizas el nombre que te genera ya no es `LoginCMSService` si se trata de `LoginCMSClient`

Comment: Lo intenté. Verdaderamente, ahora aparece LoginCMSClient, pero no me aparece el código inteligente como antes. Cómo puedo resolver eso?

Comment: te refieres al intellisense? Estas instanciando la clase LoginCMSService para acceder a los metodos que exponga

Comment: si, no estoy entendiendo mucho tu pregunta. en asp.net, intellisense me tira dodas las opciones que tengo para utilizar el servicio de afip. pero en asp.net Core, al agregarlo como servicio conectado, me aparecen menos opciones, y no me dice como se usan. ese LoginCMSClient, no lo puedo llenar con los datos que usaba en LoginCMSService, y no veo como se usa, tampoco en los pdf de la afip.

Comment: Hola como estas?, fijate si te sirve esta respuesta que implemente y pude hacerlo funcionar, eres libre de mejorarlo por supuesto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/357006/75595